# React-Native Android Gradlew installDebug results in build failure

Tags: react-native, gradlew

I am running a React-Native app but when I try to gradlew installDebug in the android directory I get a build failure. Here is the info I get when I use:

gradlew installDebug --info

`BUILD FAILED

Total time: 1.118 secs
Stopped 0 compiler daemon(s).
Received result CommandFailure[value=org.gradle.launcher.exec.ReportedException: org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.] from daemon DaemonInfo{pid=4326, address=[4c8a3b8f-5957-4911-b262-0e36824d2139 port:54258, addresses:[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, /127.0.0.1]], idle=true, context=DefaultDaemonContext[uid=dbec8c34-89ba-4872-9077-12b4b3ff38a0,javaHome=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_66.jdk/Contents/Home,daemonRegistryDir=/Users/d0ntg0m0ng/.gradle/daemon,pid=4326,idleTimeout=10800000,daemonOpts=-XX:MaxPermSize=256m,-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError,-Xmx1024m,-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8,-Duser.country=US,-Duser.language=en,-Duser.variant]}.`

This is the error I get when I run gradlew installDebug without --info
`android [router] :> ./gradlew installDebug

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

  > Cannot evaluate module react-native-couchbase-lite : Configuration with name 'default' not found.`

"react-native": "^0.15.0", is the version of react-native I am using.

[this is the repo that the project is fork from](https://gist.github.com/jchris/3c32524577deff3d69aa)
I am trying to setup the app to my genymotion emulator but the build never finishes.

I have already run the commands to react-native start and set up the sync to the couchbase lite server. Not sure if this is relevant info. I am fairly new to native development and I have no idea where to start with trying to debug this.

Answer (score 0):

include ':app'
include ':react-native-couchbase-lite'
project(':react-native-couchbase-lite').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '**../node_modules/react-native-couchbase-lite/android**')

check the file path